# getpeername() Returns Wrong Data

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am writing my first sockets program on Linux and am trying to print the IP address and port of the peer I have connected to.  I use getpeername() along with inet_ntop() and ntohs() to get the data out of the sockaddr_in struct.  When I look at the results, I get an IP address that does not go to any server that I know of (ping fails) and says that I am listening to a port that netstat says is not being used.

What am I doing wrong?  I should be getting 130.215.28.181:39000, but instead I am getting 209.94.72.137:18825 every time I run the program.  Looking at netstat shows that I am indeed listening on port 39000.

Here is a snippet from my client program:

```
connect(sockfd,&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))

// print welcome message
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
bzero(ipstr, 50);
struct sockaddr_in *address;
socklen_t address_len = sizeof(*address);
getpeername(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) address, &address_len);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &address->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof(ipstr));
printf("Connection established successfully with %s:%i!\n", ipstr, ntohs(address->sin_port));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not allocating any memory for your `sockaddr_in` structure, you's just passing a pointer to some random memory location. Instead, allocate the address structure on the stack:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(addr);
int err = getpeername(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addr_len);
if (err != 0) {
   // error
}
```

You should also be checking the return value of *every* function that is documented to return an error code. In particular, both `connect` and `getpeername` return error codes that you should be checking.

Comment: Its at moments like this that I remember why I have a strong dislike for C.

Comment: This could be bad if the address struct is actually a `sockaddr_in6`